# Sudoku by recursion gives me out of bound error - Java

Tags: java, recursion, boolean, indexoutofboundsexception, sudoku

I'm making a Sudoku solver in Java with recursion.

```
public boolean fsolve(int i, int j){
  if (j >= this.SIZE){
      i++;
      if (i>=this.SIZE){
          return true;
      }
  }
  if (!this.isEmpty(i,j)){
      return fsolve(i,j+1);
  }
  for (int curval = 1; curval < 10; curval++){
      if ((this.tryValue(curval, i, j)) && (this.fsolve(i, j+1))){
          return true;
      }
  }
  this.clear(i, j);
  return false;
  }
```

This is my solve function.

The tryValue function tries a curval at position i,j.

The clear function sets the value at position i,j to be 0.

The entire Sudoku is loaded into an int called model[][] and I have made functions to check the rows, columns and boxes. They all work as intended.

My solve function throws me and out of bounds error and I'm at a  loss. I'm not sure which way to go now, as I believe my function would work.

This is what it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
    at Field.isEmpty(Field.java:99)
    at Field.fsolve(Field.java:161)
    at Field.fsolve(Field.java:165)
    at Field.fsolve(Field.java:165)
    at Field.fsolve(Field.java:162)
    at Field.fsolve(Field.java:165)
    at Field.fsolve(Field.java:165)
    at Field.fsolve(Field.java:162)
    at Field.fsolve(Field.java:162)
    at Field.fsolve(Field.java:165)
    at Field.fsolve(Field.java:165)
    at Sudoku.main(Sudoku.java:6)
```

My solve function begins at line 152.

My isEmpty function looks like this:

```
  public boolean isEmpty(int i, int j) {
  if (this.model[i][j] == 0){
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here is my tryValue function:

```
public boolean tryValue(int val, int i, int j) {
if (!checkRow(val, i)) {
  return false;
}
if (!checkCol(val, j)) {
  return false;
}
if (!checkBox(val, i, j)) {
  return false;
}
this.model[i][j] = val;
return true;
}
```

Now, it seems like it doesn't alter model[][] at all. When I initialize the this class, I start by putting a 0 everywhere in the model[][] and then importing a file with the values for a valid Sudoku. This part works so far. When I run it now, it's as if the fsolve function doesn't do anything.

This is what it looks like after I import the file [image: Cmd output], but it's the same after the fsolve functioin.

Comment: Post your exception with stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `j>=this.SIZE`, but `i<this.SIZE`, you still call `isEmpty(i,j)`, where `j` is presumably out of bounds.  (I think you need to change `j` when you bump up `i`.)

Comment: I most definitely had to do that. Now it just gives me nothing however.

Comment: Does "gives me nothing" mean it doesn't return?  There are a LOT of combinations to try...

Comment: No, it doesn't alter model[][] at all. I'll edit OP to show my tryValue function, 2 sec.

Comment: If even one of your `check` methods returns `false`, `tryValue` will not modify `model`; since you haven't posted *that* code, I can't say if that is the problem or not.

Comment: So, apparently the code works as intended. I sent it to a friend, who got a different but still wrong result. Confused, I sent it to a second friend, and surprisingly it worked for him. My first friend didn't save the files right, so they were txt files and not sudoku files, and for me, it was my Java not working properly. After a reinstall it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean fsolve(int i, int j){
  if (j >= this.SIZE){
      i++;
      j = 0;
      if (i>=this.SIZE){
          return true;
      }
  }
```

assuming you are using a 2d grid where you want i and j to be the x and y coordinates this might solve your problem. 
If not, please provide more information.

Comment: Yes I had to do that. Now it doesn't do anything however.